# what is the meaning of this assignment,p=q where both p and q are struct pointer?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

Both `p` and `q` are `node*`. But I am little confused what does that assignment stand for?

```
struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};

void rearrange(struct node *list)
{
    struct node *p,*q;
    int temp;

    if (!list||!list->next) return;

    p=list;
    q=list->next;

    while(q)
    {
        temp=p->value;
        p->value=q->value;
        q-value=temp;p=q->next;
        q=p?p->next:0;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post exact code?

Comment: is te subject part of the question?  q is a pointer to  anode? and you are assigning q to p?

Comment: There was an extra `}` in the code you posted. I removed it. But please feel free to correct my edit if I introduced an inaccuracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title asks about `p=q`, but there is no such assignment in the code you posted.

An assignment `p=q;` would set the pointer `p` to have the same value as the pointer `q`. Thus, both `p` and `q` would point to the same place, the place `q` points to before the assignment.

Your code contains a statement `q=p?p->next:0;`. This assigns the expression `p ? p->next : 0` to `q`. The expression is evaluated in this way:

- If `p` is not zero, the value of the expression is `p->next`.
- If `p` is zero, the value of the expression is `0`.

Thus, the assignment is equivalent to “If `p` points to an object (is not zero), set `q` to `p->next`. Otherwise, set `q` to zero.”

Comment: oh,ironically it was a blunder mistake .I was actually evaluating (q=p) and was try to come up with true or false ,instead it's p which will be evaluated. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Both p and q will point to the same structure.
They are different names for the structure!